# How to create a copy of Cache in acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I would like to know how we can create a copy of the entire cache. We have a method createCopy() to create copy of a data record, is there anything similar to it?

Comment: There isn't anything like CreateCopy(..) for copying the entire cache. Moreover it is not clear to me why would you want such a thing - maybe you could provide more context?

Comment: we are using PXLoginScope to flush the updates to a different company. If we try to update the other company first and later current company, in this case even if we use PXTransactionScope, if there is any issue happened in the current company, it is not able to revert back the updates added to the different company. So we are doing the other way first update current company then the other company, this case once the cache is persisted we are not able to know what are the deleted/updated/records. so we need a copy before persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything like `CopyCache()` method in Acumatica, but caches do provide access to the modified records currently stored in them. You can access these through three properties: `PXCache.Inserted`, `PXCache.Updated`, `PXCache.Deleted`.

You may collect local copies of the records from these collections, store in some variables and push in the cache once again later.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Alex Turok Mentioned,

The Only way I found was to create a class to save the required record details like the record, extension and PXEntryStatus. Before Persist, I looped through the Cache.Cached records and got the records and save to a Local List variable of the custom class

Code for ref.

```
public class BarcodeRecord
        {
            public INItemXRef record;
            public INItemXRefExt recordExt;
            public PXEntryStatus status;
        }
                List<BarcodeRecord> barcodeRecs = new List<BarcodeRecord>();
                foreach (INItemXRef item in this.Base.itemxrefrecords.Cache.Cached)
                {
                    BarcodeRecord rec = new BarcodeRecord();
                    rec.record = item;
                    rec.recordExt = PXCache<INItemXRef>.GetExtension<INItemXRefExt>(item);
                    rec.status = this.Base.itemxrefrecords.Cache.GetStatus(item);
                    barcodeRecs.Add(rec);
                }
```

Note: My task of copying information fro one company to otherstill seems not working! #WorkingWithAcumatica